# spyder 3.x closing parenthesis hangs when heavy data in memory

Tags: spyder, python-3.7

I am working with lots of Pandas dataframe and dictionaries in memory, i realise the more data there is, the more Spyder will hang when you type closing parenthesis the the console.
Does anyone know how to fix this? i already disable most options.

[image: preference screen]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Please go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Display`

and deactivate the option called `Display ballon tips`.

Comment: hi, didnt have that option.

Comment: You have the right option deactivated. But what if you reduce the `Buffer` size to just 500? That could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: nope, its not, the hanging only happen when my dataframes in memory got like GB of data. when the data is a few hundred mb

Comment: It could also be a problem with the Jedi support in IPython. We added an option to deactivate it, but I don't remember if it's present in Spyder 3 (it should apoear in the Advanced tab). If not, you need to google how to do it by evaluating code in the console.

Comment: yeah, i disabled all that too from advance settings of ipython console.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know what could fix it. However, we haven't heard about this problem in a long time, so my last advice is to install our 4.2.5 version using conda or pip in a virtualenv and try again.

Comment: i actually tried that too, problem exist in 4.x spyder too.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. Unfortunately we don't have an easy way to test that use case to understand what's happening.